# I have germany student visa. But now I want Dubai student visa for bachelors. Masters back next year in Germany. Can I retain my Germany student visa?

Tags: germany, student-visa

I came to Germany on 15th Oct 21, on a Bachelors visa. But I am not able get my credits transferred, which I studied in India for 2 yrs Bachelor in Mechanical engg. I am planning to go to Dubai for my Bachelors now. Aftet that I want to return to Germany for my Masters after 1-1.5 yr. Can I retain my Germany student visa even though I am studying in Dubai with a Dubai student visa?

Comment: Study visas are typically tied to the intended course of study, irrespective of the country that issues the visa. It’s vanishingly unlikely that you would be able to retain your visa if you abandon your current course

Answer (score 2):

If you leave the country for more than 6 months and without intention to live as a resident, you cannot keep the permit.